# Visual Studio not generating debug executable?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, visual-studio-2015, project

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2015 to write a C++ program. Recently I've been getting an error in which the debugger can't locate the executable file generated by the build. I've tried almost every solution out there but I can't fix it. I even tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 and it worked for a little while but now I keep getting the same error. It starts happening after I write code for a bit.

I verified that the Linker and the Debug both access the same location for the .exe file. What could cause the .exe file to not generate? My build compiles successfully without error.

Here is the error:

`Unable to start program 'c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project1\debug\Project1.exe`

EDIT: The only virus scanner I have is MalwareBytes, but this hasn't happened before when I had it installed.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I was writing my program using a `.h` file but it needed to be `.cpp`.